# Taking texture from Image and drawing it in QQuickFramebufferObject. Not all instances are rendered

Tags: qt, opengl, qml, qtquick2

**What I'm doing, in short**:

- Deriving a `MyItem` class from `QQuickFramebufferObject`
- In `MyItem` I have a `QQuickItem* sourceItem` property from which I fetch a texture and draw it in a triangle
- From QML I supply an Image called `sourceItem` to `MyItem`. This Image has `cache: false`
- When the Image finishes loading, I wait one frame and then call `update` on `MyItem`
- I have a 6x6 grid of `MyItem` instances

The problem is that some of the instances of `MyItem` draw nothing:

[image: screenshot]

Any ideas?

My code:

*main.cpp*:

```
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickFramebufferObject>
#include <QOpenGLFramebufferObject>
#include <QSGTextureProvider>
#include <QSGTexture>
#include <QQuickWindow>
#include <QOpenGLBuffer>
#include <QOpenGLShaderProgram>
#include <QOpenGLFunctions>
#include "propertyhelper.h" // this file is from http://syncor.blogspot.bg/2014/11/qt-auto-property.html

class MyItem : public QQuickFramebufferObject {
    Q_OBJECT

    AUTO_PROPERTY(QQuickItem*, sourceItem)

public:
    Renderer *createRenderer() const;
};

class MyItemRenderer : public QQuickFramebufferObject::Renderer, protected QOpenGLFunctions {
public:
    MyItemRenderer() {
        initializeOpenGLFunctions();

        m_program.addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Vertex,
            "in highp vec2 aPos;\
            out highp vec2 vTexCoord;\
            \
            void main() {\
                gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 0.0, 1.0);\
                vTexCoord = aPos * .5  + .5;\
            }"
        );
        m_program.addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Fragment,
            "in highp vec2 vTexCoord;\
            out vec4 outputColor;\
            uniform sampler2D uTex;\
            \
            void main() {\
                outputColor = texture(uTex, vTexCoord);\
            }"
        );
        m_program.link();
        m_program.setUniformValue("uTex", 0);

        createGeometry();
    }

    void synchronize(QQuickFramebufferObject* qqfbo){
        auto item = (MyItem*)qqfbo;

        m_window = item->window();
        m_tex = item->sourceItem()->textureProvider()->texture();
    }

    QOpenGLFramebufferObject *createFramebufferObject(const QSize &size) {
        QOpenGLFramebufferObjectFormat format;
        format.setAttachment(QOpenGLFramebufferObject::CombinedDepthStencil);
        return new QOpenGLFramebufferObject(size, format);
    }

    void paintGeometry() {
        m_program.enableAttributeArray("aPos");
        m_program.setAttributeArray("aPos", m_vertices.constData());
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, m_vertices.size());
        m_program.disableAttributeArray("aPos");
    }

    void createGeometry() {
        m_vertices << QVector2D(-1, -1);
        m_vertices << QVector2D(1, -1);
        m_vertices << QVector2D(-1, 1);
    }

    void render() {
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        m_program.bind();

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        m_tex->bind();
        paintGeometry();

        m_window->resetOpenGLState();
    }

private:
    QQuickWindow* m_window;
    QVector<QVector2D> m_vertices;
    QSGTexture* m_tex;
    QOpenGLShaderProgram m_program;
};

QQuickFramebufferObject::Renderer *MyItem::createRenderer() const {
    return new MyItemRenderer();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    qmlRegisterType<MyItem>("MyItem", 1, 0, "MyItem");
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

*main.qml*:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    id: window
    width: 600
    height: 600

    Flow {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Repeater {
            model: 36
            delegate: MyItemWrapper {
                width: 100
                height: 100
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*MyItemWrapper.qml*:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import MyItem 1.0

Item {
    Image {
        x: -100000 // hide the sourceItem
        id: sourceItem
        layer.enabled: true
        source: "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTg2MTMyMzU0M15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwOTU3ODk4NTE@._V1_SX300.jpg"
        cache: false

        function updateCppItemOnce() {
            window.afterRendering.disconnect(updateCppItemOnce);
            cppItem.update();
        }

        onStatusChanged: {
            if (status == Image.Ready) {
                window.afterRendering.connect(updateCppItemOnce);
            }
        }
    }

    MyItem {
        sourceItem: sourceItem
        anchors.fill: parent
        id: cppItem
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

- I tried enabling OpenGL logging but got no messages
- I've tried the testcase on 3 other PCs, all of them much weaker/slower than this one. The bug doesn't occur on them. So I think the bug happens only on fast PCs - it may be a timing problem.

Comment: How can this be offtopic?

Comment: ​@StefanMonov From the rules: "_Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the_ **shortest code necessary** _to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example._" (emphasis mine)

Comment: @DonaldDuck: I'm aware of that rule. And indeed, I have put much effort into bringing the testcase to a minimal length. The reason it doesn't seem so is that **reproducing my problem requires using a low-level API** (OpenGL), which requires a lot of boilerplate for even the simplest things. This is unavoidable. Also considerable is the boilerplate for integrating Qt with OpenGL. Finally, I was aware that even my minimal testcase is quite long, and so I included the "What I'm doing, in short" bullet list at the top, to ease understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I now realized that instead of the clunky way I was calling `update()`, I could just connect to the `item->sourceItem()->textureProvider()->textureChanged()` signal. Did that and now it works like a charm.

I'd still like to know why my original way fails, though :)

Answer (score 0):

Gunnar Sletta provided the solution as a comment in [my bugreport](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-62777).

> I suspect the problem is your use of the 'afterRendering' signal. When running on a threaded render loop this signal will fire when rendering is done and the slot will be called almost right away on the main thread. Depending on where the threaded render loop is when the image completes loading that means you'll have the slot invoked potentially right away. When the scene graph reaches the sync phase, the order in which nodes are processed is arbitrary, so some nodes may be processed before the image and some after. Those processed before the image gets a texture gets null and those processed after gets a valid texture.
>
> It would be better to connect to afterSynchronization signal as this would actually fire first after the synchronization of the Image was guaranteed to have completed.

Indeed, using `afterSynchronizing` fixed my problem.